# Failed to store stdin state and compare it in C++

Tags: c++, eof

```
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int input;

    while (true)
    {
        cin >> input;
        ios_base::iostate state = cin.rdstate();

        if (state == ios_base::eofbit)
    //  if (state == (ios_base::eofbit | ios_base::failbit)) doesn't work also
            break;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Why it never stops when `^D` (EOF, `^Z` in Windows) is pressed?

Comment: I suggest you do `while (cin >> input) { ... }` instead. This relies on the fact that the input operator function returns a reference to the stream, and that a stream can be used as a boolean expression.

Comment: If you're going to use `rdstate()`, then the test should be `((state & ios_base::eofbit) != 0)`, or something equivalent.

Comment: As for your problem, the name of `eofbit` should give you a hint, it's a *bit* and the state can be multiple bits ored together.

Answer (score 2):

Failure to read the formatted input sets `failbit` as well as `eofbit`. To test for `eof`, check just that bit:

```
if (state & ios_base::eofbit) // if you like verbosity
if (cin.eof())                // if you like brevity
```

Comment: How about using `state == (ios_base::failbit | ios_base::eofbit)`?

Comment: @KevinDong: Yeah, you can do that. But then what about `badbit`? Prefer just `!state` if you want to handle the lot of them. But in your question you seemed specifically to want to check `eofbit`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Though I don't really understand why `state == (ios_base::failbit | ios_base::eofbit)` still doesn't work, I would choose `if (cin.eof()) ` because it seems more easy to handle.

Comment: @KevinDong: Probably because you forgot about `badbit`. I already said that. And "easy to handle" does not always equate to "gives the right answers".